# Check box change event is not working in firefox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Here is my code. This code is not working in mozilla firefox browser.

**My Html**

```
<input class="staff_check" name="select_staff" type="checkbox" value="@Model.Caregivers[i].AgencyUserID" />
```

**Script**

```
        var selected_staff = [];
        var selected_staff_names = [];
        $('input[name="select_staff"').change(function () {
            console.log('ds');
            if (this.checked) {
                selected_staff.push($(this).val());
                selected_staff_names.push('<span class="selected_staff">' + $(this).parent('label').text().trim() + '</span>');
            }
            else {
                var idx = $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_staff);
                if (idx > -1) {
                    selected_staff.splice(idx, 1);
                    selected_staff_names.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

This works fine in google chrome. But it'nt work in mozilla firefox.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QnFg3/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/gj6ramg2/6/ @Manoz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed closing square bracket '`]`', change:

```
...
$('input[name="select_staff"').change(function () {
....
```

to

```
...
$('input[name="select_staff"]').change(function () {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `change()` function, try `click()`:

```
var selected_staff = [];
        var selected_staff_names = [];
        $('input[name="select_staff"]').click(function () {
            console.log('ds');
            if (this.checked) {
                selected_staff.push($(this).val());
                selected_staff_names.push('<span class="selected_staff">' + $(this).parent('label').text().trim() + '</span>');
            }
            else {
                var idx = $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_staff);
                if (idx > -1) {
                    selected_staff.splice(idx, 1);
                    selected_staff_names.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks. The change event does not work on Firefox 39.0 (Linux).